# How to list all the ip addresses in a Google cloud subnet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I want list all the ip addresses that are used in a subnet and who is using them. I want to do that via the Google console (or gcloud command). Point is that I do not want to do a ping against all the ip's in the subnet to find that out - I am aware of this process but it is not practical when you have a large setup.
Another reason to ask for doing this via Google Console is that we can do this very easily using Azure Portal.

Hoping someone can help.
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried something? At least read any commands in gcloud documentation that could help?

Answer (score 2):

Ping is not a reliable method to determine IP address usage. Ping requires the ICMP protocol to be enabled which is often not the case.

Internal IP addresses are either statically allocated, which you can list, or DHCP allocated, which you cannot list.

No single command will meet your objective. The closest is [gcloud compute addresses list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list), which only lists statically allocated IP addresses.

You could use a combination of commands such as `gcloud compute instances list` and `gcloud asset list` to create a list of resources and then parse IP addresses.

In summary, you must write a script that combines commands and parses the output. It might be easy in Azure, but in Google Cloud, there are numerous network adapters, interfaces, connectors, gateways, proxies, etc and no command provides a single method of listing all IP addresses.

Once you have created a list it will become obsolete as soon as a service is launched (started/created/rebooted) or reconfigured. The VPC environment is predominately dynamic.

Comment: gcloud compute instances list does not display the compute nodes used by GKE in autopilot mode. GKE autopilot uses up ip addresses but does not show up in the list. Tried the other two commands but they are not helpful either.

Comment: @souser - As I said, there is no single command. You mention in your comment that the commands are not helpful. Edit your question to show what you tried and why the results are not helpful. State information with facts and details and not generalized comments such as **not helpfile**. As written your question is about to be closed - I recommend putting effort into the question and problem description.